# How to pass data from Spring backend to Angular frontend?

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, architecture, microservices

I know my question is a bit general, but I couldn't find anything on this. How do you pass data from the Spring backend to the Angular front end?
What would be the best approach?

A quick example:

I want to develop a microservice to be integrated from other system. I want to provide a REST interface with which the user can trigger events in the frontend.
Now when a user makes a REST request, how do I pass the message to the Angular frontend?

Frontend -> Backend REST

Backend -> Frontend ????

Comment: There is multiple way to do it, you can use long pooling, web socket or a library. I personaly prefer web socket but it might be challenging. And you must ensure your target browsers support web socket protocol.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

Answer (score 1):

First you can define an endpoint with Spring Boot:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/test", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> test() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello world");
}
```

For development you would need to turn off CORS:

```
@Profile("dev")
@Configuration
public class CorsConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedMethods("GET")
            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
       }
}
```

and then you can easily subscribe on data in Angular method:

```
onClick(): void {
this.subscribed = this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/test', {responseType: 'text'})
      .subscribe(data => this.message = data);
}
```

Comment: This would only describe the communication path from the frontend to the backend. The approach I am looking for is from backend to frontend. As @ierhalim already commented this would be possible for example via web socket or long pooling.